# How to pause KCL client in Java

Tags: amazon-kcl

We have a Spring application using the Java KCL client to consume records off of an Kinesis stream. Is there a way we could somehow 'pause' the KCL to stop processing records and then restart it later safely? What would be the recommended way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to stop and restart the worker. As a work around, you can call worker.shutdown() and create a new worker when you want to start processing records again. Please note that you would also want to call shutdown() on AmazonDynamoDBStreamsAdapterClient. Shutting down just the worker will not stop KCL from processing records.